excel found a problem with one or more formula references in this worksheet in a new workbook after only inserting one table
I created a new excel workbook and inserted one table. When I fill in a cell in the row below the table then due to autoexpansion the table is expanded with one row. Exacty how it supposed toe work.
When I open another worksheek that has many (more than 1000) defined names and return to my workbook with the table then filling in a cell below the table causes the following error:
"excel found a problem with one or more formula references in this worksheet in a new workbook after only inserting one table
Check that the cell references, range names, defined names and links to other workbooks in your formulas are all correct "
Why do I get this error and how to solve it?
Also helpful, Is there a way to stop excel from showing this message
Additional info:
My workbook with the 1000 defined names works fine. However adding a table in a NEW worksheet in that workbook gives the same error so I tried adding a table in a new empty workbook
Why does another new workbook or another new worksheet causes this behaviour? There can't be any references to either the new workbook nor the new worksheet
I did another test.
Startingpoint: No excel processes running
Open excel, new workbook, insert table and fill in cell below the last row.
=> Everything works as expected. No errors.
Now open my excel sheet with the named fields.
Going back to the workbook with the table, fill a cell below the last row. => The error about the references pops up
How can another workbook causing a totally different workbook to generate an error?

Did you check that both tables (the old one in the working workbook and the new one in the new empty workbook) got different table names?

Thanks for your reply.
Maybe I wasn't clear. I have a workbook with many defined field. Inserted a new worksheet and on that sheet Inserted a table with headers and got the
error when I filled a cel below the last row.
At that point I removed the inserted worksheet and tried a new table in a new workbook. The same error occured. At this point the original workbook was open as well as the new workbook.
After closing the original workbook with the define names the new workbook with the table didn't give an error anymore
